# flaks and pymongo failing to connect to my database returning pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: python-3.x, flask, postman, pymongo, flask-restful

Each time I try to test my registration Api using postman i get internal server error as the returned error message whereas on my terminal i get this error

```
 [2020-01-05 07:14:52,933] ERROR in app: Exception on /register [POST]
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
web_1  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
web_1  |     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 458, in wrapper
web_1  |     resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 89, in view
web_1  |     return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 573, in dispatch_request
web_1  |     resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "app.py", line 99, in post
web_1  |     if UserExist(username):
web_1  |   File "app.py", line 20, in UserExist
web_1  |     count =  db.users.count_documents({"Username": username})
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1720, in count_documents
web_1  |     return self.__database.client._retryable_read(
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1453, in _retryable_read
web_1  |     server = self._select_server(
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1253, in _select_server
web_1  |     server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 233, in select_server
web_1  |     return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 192, in select_servers
web_1  |     server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 208, in _select_servers_loop
web_1  |     raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
web_1  | pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: :27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
web_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2020 07:14:52] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

below is my registration and user checking codes

```
class Register(Resource):
    def post(self):
        postedData = request.get_json()
        username = postedData["username"]
        password = postedData["password"]

        if UserExist(username):
            retJson = {
                "status code": 301,
                "message": "Invalid username"
            }
            return jsonify(retJson)
        hashed_pw = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
        users.inser({
            "Username": username,
            "Password": hashed_pw
        })
        retJson = {
            "status code": 200,
            "message": "successfully registered"
        }

        return jsonify(retJson)

def UserExist(username):
    count =  db.users.count_documents({"Username": username})
    if count <= 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I have tried every trick I can think please any idea what is wrong and how I can fix this thank you.

Comment: We need to see how you are creating your db variable and the parameters you are passing to MongoClient

Comment: check if mongodb server is running or not??

Comment: @vikas yes my mongodb server is runing

Comment: @Belly here is how I created my db

client = MongoClient("mongodb://:27017")
db = client.SimDB
users = db["Users"]

# for admin
admin = db["Admin"]

Comment: Have you created  route for this by api.add??

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the MongoClient connection; you have:

```
MongoClient("mongodb://:27017")
```

I suggest it needs to be:

```
MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
```

Comment: this did not work rather the error now is now this pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: substitute localhost for the servername or IP address where mongodb is running. Ensure you have connectivity to that server from wherever the code is running.

Comment: Still having same error connection refused its flagging this function
def UserExist(username):
    if users.count_documents({"Username":username})==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

Comment: Can you connect from the shell e.g. at your command prompt type `mongo mongodb://<YourMongoServerName>:27017`

Comment: A 111 error is likely to be either firewall, or IP binding. Are you running mongodb on a different machine to the python program?